# Is it necessary to run the rake assets:precompile command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a situation where it is not necessary to run this command? i.e. I don't have static images in the assets directory

Comment: Not on development env

Comment: Can you expand a little bit?

Comment: On production env you need to if you have set precompile config to `true`

Comment: For which environment you are asking development or production

Comment: Okay so my current knowledge about when to run this command is when everytime I made changes on my custom.scss file. So my sequence is, I run `rake assets:precompile`, commit changes, push to github, then push to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku includes asset precompilation as a step in the deploy process. As I see you're using Heroku, that means that you don't have to run `rake assets:precompile` before committing or pushing. Just make sure that the code that needs to be preprocessed is included in the commit that you're pushing (i.e. the files in `/app/assets/(javascripts|stylesheets)` etc are up to date).

If you're only deploying to Heroku and working locally in the "development" environment, then you might consider adding `/public/assets` to your `.gitignore` and deleting that folder.

See the [Heroku docs on this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-during-slug-compilation).